# Incognito on Chrome running on Windows 10 disappeared

Tags: windows-10

The incognito option on Chrome running on Windows 10 disappeared this morning. Searching did not yield anything on what caused the option to disappear and more importantly how to restore it back. I tried, the usual gotos, restarting the browser and the machine with little success. How can I get the incognito mode back on the browser?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Open **`regedit`** from Windows start menu or by pressing Windows Key + r:

[image]

**Step 2:** Go to the location: `HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome`:

[image]

**Step 3:** In this location, you will find a key named `IncognitoModeAvailability`, Right click on this key & press delete button:

[image]

**Step 4:** Restart Google Chrome & Check if Incognito menu option is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a solution, to enable incongnito option, using the recommendation here - http://www.openguru.com/2016/12/how-to-enable-incognito-mode-in-google_1.html.
This article describes deleting the registry entry - HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
The only change that I made is that instead of deleting the key - IncognitoModeAvailability, I reset the value from 1 to 0. 
What caused it to be set to 1 in the 1st place, a policy or a script, I'm still unsure.

Comment: You should quote and cite all relevant information from your link.  This is to insure your answer is helpful, even if, your reference link no longer works in the future.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't see "New Incognito window" option when you right click on Chrome icon on task bar, so you can watch the video on youtube link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-ynktSPk_k

[YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-ynktSPk_k)

Comment: A link-only answer is likely to become unhelpful at sometime in the future. If this offers something new that the year-old answer doesn't cover, include it in the body of the answer.